# Can selenium catch the browser - "Waiting for www.google.com" type info at the bottom?

Tags: firefox, browser, selenium

Does any one know of a way for selenium to capture the `"Waiting for www.google.com"` type of info that is displayed on the bottom left/right of a browser?

The purpose of obtaining this message is, so that I can avoid taking a full-screen(as compared to browser screen capture) shot to capture if a page does not load.

I dont want to only know if a page does not load, I also want to know what went wrong. As all these scripts are running off jenkins, on a remote server and there is no physical eye monitoring how the scripts run.

Any help will be much appreciated,

Comment: You can inject javascript to get window.status but it requires the browser to be configured to allow it.

Comment: You can also just use the driver.findElement method which will try and find the specified element for x seconds (set by driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(x, TimeUnit.SECONDS). The function will throw an exception after the time has elapsed, in which case you can add some error info or take a screenshot etc. This assumes you know of a specific element which will appear once the page has loaded.

Comment: Well I am actually not waiting for a particular element. the information that I want is -- for example. While loading a page, even though all the elements have been loaded the page is not completely loaded, cause it is waiting on a response from www.google-analytics.com. So while waiting for the page to load, when the page fails to load because of google-analytics. I wanna know that.

Comment: Also @mouse food , do you know the javascript? i assume i would need to use $sel->get_eval($javascript);